# URLFetchApp returns an error after third try

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is my google script:
function doAll(){

```
var url = 'https://myherokuapp.herokuapp.com/createfacultylist';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var json = response.getContentText();
var data = JSON.parse(json);
Browser.msgBox(data.message);

var url2 = 'https://myherokuapp.herokuapp.com/updatefacultylist';
var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2);
var json2 = response2.getContentText();
var data2 = JSON.parse(json2);
Browser.msgBox(data2.message);    

var url3 = 'https://myherokuapp.herokuapp.com/test';
var response3 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url3);
var json3 = response3.getContentText();
var data3 = JSON.parse(json3);
Browser.msgBox(data2.message);    

}
```

It goes okay after the first two calls of the script, but when I call it for the third time it returns:

> Request failed for https://myherokuapp.herokuapp.com/createfacultylist
>   returned code 503. Truncated server response:  
>      ... (use muteHttpExceptions
>   option to examine full response)

Comment: if it worked twice then it should not be a script problem, but a url problem (error 503 mean the service is unavailable )

Answer (score 0):

Try to throttle your calls by inserting:

`utilities.sleep(1000`)